# What is the standard convention or rule to write javascript for a web page and why?

Tags: javascript

What is the standard convention to write javascript for a **web page** (code will not be used anywhere else). I ask this because i am always confused as to which technique to follow? And if lets say i have to write a shared code / utility lib, then which is the best technique? Let me know if there are other ways too?
I am sharing some techniques which i know of. What is the difference between each and when should you use below technique?

example 1:

```
((function (mine) {
   mine.foo = 'this is a property';

   mine.bar = function(){
      return 'this is a function with ' + mine.foo;
   };
})(window.mine = window.mine || {});
alert(mine.bar());
```

example 2:

```
 var mine = function(){};
 mine.foo = 'this is a property';    
 mine.bar = function(){
    return 'this is a function with ' + mine.foo;
 }
 alert(mine.bar());
```

example 3:

```
var mine = {
    'foo' : ' this is a property ',
    'bar' : function(){
         return ' this is a function with '+ mine.foo;
     } 
};
alert(mine.bar());
```

example 4:

```
function Mine() {
    this.foo = 'this is a property';
}
Mine.prototype.bar = function(var1){
    return ' this is a function with '+ this.foo;
};
var mine = new Mine();
alert(mine.bar());
```

example 5:

```
var foo = 'this is a property';
function bar(){
    return ' this is a function with '+ foo;
}
alert(bar());
```

Thanks

**EDIT**: [JavaScript-Module-Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) is the way to go IMO

Comment: Sorry, this type of question is subjective and off-topic for SO.

Comment: The first 3 are almost the same. With the forth example you use a constructor function and bar function is shared through prototype chain - which is more efficient.

Comment: Where can I get an answer if not SO?plus I am asking for a reason too, and  not just answer

Comment: Perhaps rather than asking what's the correct way to do it, which has no objective law book answer, you could rephrase to ask what's the difference between those four types of definitions and if there are any de facto standards on their usage.

Comment: #4 is unnecessary and inefficient if you only want to create a single `mine` instance.    #2 should not use an empty function, but `{}`.

Comment: You are doing different things in all your examples, so it depends on what you want to achieve. In #1 and #3 `mine` is an object, but in #1 you're not polluting the global scope. In #2 and #4 `mine` is a function, but only option #4 allows you to create multiple instances, #2 is actually rather silly because there is no point making `mine` an empty function if you treat it as an object anyway without accessing its prototype.